# Is there a way to return an isolated variable from an isolated function?

Tags: ballerina

```
import ballerina/http;

isolated json[] outputIso = [];

service on new http:Listener(9090) {
    isolated resource function get invictScanList() returns json|error {
        return outputIso;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error for the above code

```
invalid access of an 'isolated' variable outside a 'lock' statement(BCE3962)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by the error message, have to use a lock statement when accessing an isolated variable. Moreover, the return statement will have to be updated so that the expression is an isolated expression.

ex:

```
lock {
    return outputIso.clone();
}
```

For more details

- https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/isolated-variables
- https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/#concurrency-safety